# How to continue syncing the newest data after importing snapshot data completed

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I'm trying to sync the newest data from Cardano-db-sync, but after importing snapshot data successfully. I don't know how to continue to sync new data in realtime.

There is an example here https://github.com/IntersectMBO/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/docker.md#restore-from-snapshot. However, it's not specified how the *.lstate file is used as a parameter to insert new data only.

Once I run the below command, old data is also being inserted.

```
RESTORE_SNAPSHOT=https://update-cardano-mainnet.iohk.io/cardano-db-sync/db-sync-snapshot-schema-10-block-6014140-x86_64.tgz \
docker-compose up && docker-compose logs -f
```

Anyone could help, please?

Thank you

Comment: After importing a snapshot, `db-sync` should just start following the chain.